# OnFragmentInteractionListener showing up null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've searched and searched for this question and tried many different solutions but nothing seems to be working.

I'm trying to access an object in my fragment layout but its turning up null and I realize that my OnFragmentInteractionListener is null which is leading me to believe it's not attracting the right fragment.

This is pretty much a copy paste from another activity of the app and that activity works perfectly fine. For some reason, this one just does not want to communicate.

***TLDR: mListener in my Fragment (negativeThoughtView.java) is null***

I only included the important parts of the code to shorten it:

**Activity (JournalView.java)**

```
public class JournalView extends AppCompatActivity implements negativeThoughtView.OnFragmentInteractionListener, distortionView.OnFragmentInteractionListener, challengingThoughtView.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    TabLayout thoughtsTab;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PagerAdapterView adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_journal_view);

        thoughtsTab = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.thoughtsViewTabs);
        thoughtsTab.addTab(thoughtsTab.newTab().setText("Negative Thoughts"));
        thoughtsTab.addTab(thoughtsTab.newTab().setText("Distortions"));
        thoughtsTab.addTab(thoughtsTab.newTab().setText("Challenging Thoughts"));
        thoughtsTab.setTabGravity(thoughtsTab.GRAVITY_FILL);

        adapter = new PagerAdapterView(getSupportFragmentManager(), thoughtsTab.getTabCount());

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.thoughtsViewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(thoughtsTab));

        thoughtsTab.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        negativeThoughtView NegativeThoughtView =(negativeThoughtView) adapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, 0);
        distortionView DistortionView =(distortionView) adapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, 1);
        challengingThoughtView ChallengingThoughtView =(challengingThoughtView) adapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, 2);

        if (NegativeThoughtView != null) {
            String negativeThoughts = "Tester";
            NegativeThoughtView.onButtonPressed(negativeThoughts);
        }
        if (ChallengingThoughtView != null) {
            String challengingThoughts= "Tester";
            ChallengingThoughtView.onButtonPressed(challengingThoughts);
        }
        if (DistortionView != null) {
            String distortions= "Tester";
            DistortionView.onButtonPressed(distortions);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }

    @Override
    public void negativeThoughtView(String string) {

    }

    @Override
    public void challengingThoughtView(String string) {

    }

    @Override
    public void distortionView(String string) {

    }
}
```

**Fragment (negativeThoughtsView.java)**

```
public class negativeThoughtView extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    TextView negativeThoughtEntry;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public negativeThoughtView() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static negativeThoughtView newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        negativeThoughtView fragment = new negativeThoughtView();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_negative_thought_view, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        negativeThoughtEntry = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.negativeThoughtEntry3);
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(String negativeThought) {
        Log.d("Passer","1");
        if (mListener != null) {
            Log.d("Passer","2");
            negativeThoughtEntry.setText(negativeThought);
            //mListener.negativeThoughtView(negativeThought);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
            Log.d("Passer","mListener good");
        } else {
            Log.d("Passer","mListener null");
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
        void negativeThoughtView(String string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your listener is only instantiated if "if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener)" is true. Is the statement true?

Comment: Yes, I believe so because, if I'm correct, the term `A instanceOf B` means `B` is implemented in `A`. And in this case - `OnFragmentInteractoinListener` is implemented because the class header of `JournalView` implements `OnFragmentInteractionListener` as can be seen in the phrase `negativeThoughtView.OnFragmentInteractionListener`

Comment: can you try changing "if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener)" to "if (context instanceof negativeThoughtView.OnFragmentInteractionListener)"?

Comment: Also, can you try putting a breakpoint at that line of code I just mentioned and seeing if "mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;" is executed?

Comment: Alright so in that line in `onAttach` (`if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener)`) IS true but for some reason, it runs to `onAttach` after `onButtonPressed()`. So mListener isn't initiated yet. So i just need to figure out how to move my code around so it runs to `onAttach` first